# Como fazer um Insert pegando dados do FORM em Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, querybuilder

estou vendo a documentação do Laravel sobre dbquery, no caso insert.
Eu preciso fazer o insert fora do método resource (manualmente.

Tipo:

```
DB::table('users')->insert(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
);
```

Mas preciso pegar os dados de um form. Como faço isto? Não vi na documentaqção.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller:

```
$model = new Model;
$model->nome = $request->get('nome'); // Vem do Form
$model->email = $request->get('email'); // Vem do Form
$model->telefone = $request->get('telefone'); // Vem do Form

$model->save();
```

Comment: Agora entendi. Vou testar mas era isto que precisa saber. Valeu.

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa apontar o seu formulario para a rota onde o destino seja a função que você ira efetuar a inserção, por exemplo;

Seu form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('cadastro/novo') }}">
...
</form>
```

Sua Rota:

`Route::post('cadastro/novo', 'UsuariosController@create');`

No Controller `UsuariosController` você pode usar a classe `User` para fazer manipulação dos dados do BD porque todo model esta atrelado a uma tabela no banco de dados PORÉM no plural, por exemplo;

model `user` -> tabela `users`

model `cat` -> tabela `cats`

```
use App\User;

class UsuarioController extends Controller {

// A função Request tera todos os dados enviados via post.
public function create(Request $request) {

    // Pega os dados enviado atraves do POST exceto o input _token 
    // que é enviado por padrão atraves do form.
    $dados = $request->except('_token');

    // A inserção acontece aqui...
    User::create($dados);
}
```

Para realizar buscar no banco de dados você pode continuar usando o model que deseja pois ele já tem diversos métodos para facilitar a manipulação.

```
$user = User::find(1); // Busca o usuario com o ID 1
$user = User::where('nome', 'oNome'); // Busca o usuario onde o campo "nome" seja "oNome".
```

No caso de udpate você pode fazer;

```
User::where('id', 999)->update(['sobrenome' => 'novoSobreNome']);
// Buscara e atualizara o usuário com ID 999 substituindo o campo sobrenome com "novoSobreNome"
```

OU

```
$user = User::where('id', 999);
$user->idade += 1;
$user->save();
```

Você pode consultar todos os métodos disponíveis  [acessando a pagina do `Eloquent`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent) do laravel.

Comment: Mas um dos campos é um código e preciso somar 1 a este código antes de dar o insert. Como poderia fazer isto?

Comment: Todos os models possuem métodos para busca de informação como por exemplo o `where`, então você precisa primeiramente buscar o dado que você quer no banco de dados para realizar o update e/ou enviar o update direto.

Comment: Eu já estou jogando do action do form para a função abaixo no controller e funcionou/;
    public function gravaOrdem()
    {
        $codigomaior =  DB::table('ordemservicos')->max('codigoos');
        $codigomaior = $codigomaior + 1;
        return $codigomaior;

Comment: Isso aí que você está querendo o próprio MySql já faz quando se coloca a coluna `auto_increment`.

Comment: @MarcosBirro sim, desta maneira também funciona, veja a alteração que fiz.

Comment: O campo não pode ser autoincrement. Já tenho o ID como chave prim´ria e autoincrement.
Preciso fazer manualmente mas pelo exemplo com a model acredito que vai funcionar porque vou pegar campo a campo e poderei somar um ao código (Que não é chabe primária).

Comment: Eu testei e está dando um erro no $request.

Comment: ErrorException in OrdemServicoController.php line 293:
Undefined variable: request

Comment: Mas está declarada?:

Comment: class OrdemservicoController extends Controller
{
    protected $request;
    
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

Comment: você não precisa definir o objeto de `Request´ como atributo da classe, use apenas como `$request->`